# How to fill an array with numbers till certrain number in Java that user has entered?

Tags: java, arrays

I would appreciate any help on this problem that I have:
User enters a numeric value, like 6.
Now program has to fill out an array of 20 elements:

```
for (i=0; i <= 20; i++)
```

But I need to fill an array till certain number that the user has entered, for example if User entered 6
then the output must be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2
```

Or if user entered 2, the output must be:

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Arrays element count needs to be 20, not more, not less.

I get stuck in the place where I need to define that the arrays maximum valued element must be the one the User has written.
Will appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Your loop should end at `i < 20`, not `i <= 20` if you actually want 20 elements.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the Modulo operator? In Java, the modulo operator allows someone to get the remainder of a division. For example: `4 % 3 = 1`, and `3 % 3 = 0`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 1):

Because this is homework, I’ll give you direction rather than code.

The modulus operator `%` returns the remainder after division.

Consider how the result of the following operation relates to the value of the desired element at index `i`:

```
i % userInput
```

Answer (score 0):

Modulo operator is your friend here.

Just iterate  ( for loop  from 0 to 19 )  over array you have to fill and put  index % userValue + 1 into it

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Modulo operator and it worked like a charm to solve this problem. And Bohemian, you are right, it is for a homework. Thank you, my question is answered.